# Python program issue when pointing to folder on cell phone (Samsung Galaxy S5)

Tags: python

I'm working on a Python program to simply pull files from a folder location on my laptop and bring them into a folder location on my cell phone, which is a Samsung Galaxy S5. I had success when testing this out with 2 folders on my desktop, but it can't seem to find the location on my cell phone. Can someone help?

Source Code:

```
importos
importshutil
importglob
fordatainglob.glob('C:/Users/Shane/Music/Transfer Files/*.mp3'):
    shutil.move(data, 'This PC\Shane (Galaxy S5)\Card\Music')
```

Error Message:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'This
>   PC\Shane (Galaxy S5)\Card\Music'

Comment: `'This PC\Shane (Galaxy S5)\Card\Music'` is not a valid path.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation as to what may be a usable path for a connected device?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove 'This PC' and replace it with partition name to which you want to move data for example 'F:'. And replace '\' with '/' or two back slashes and also I think there is no need of 'os' module.

importshutil
importglob
fordatainglob.glob('C:/Users/Shane/Music/Transfer Files/*.mp3'):
    shutil.move(data, 'F:/Shane (Galaxy S5)/Card/Music')

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried changing from 'This PC' to 'F:' and still seem to get the same message. Are there other partitions that may be available to utilize?

Comment: Sorry for late replay. Replace back slashes with slashes in the link to which you want to move. And I have just given you an example that use 'F:' but you have to use actual partition name, in which there is a folder into which you want to move you files.